# Form handeling with an array of object Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have to update a vuex store that contains a array of object such as:

My user have a combobox of choice and when it choose one it update a property of this object in the database

But each time i choose a item in my autocomplete (the combobox here) i get the `[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.` error. So i was wondering if vuex allows it or if i have to change the way i'm doing it.

I'am using Nuxt, with an API using express and a mongodb database

My vuex :

state:

```js
export default () => ({
  kivaferkoi: {
    picked: [],
    notYetPicked: []
  }
})
```

mutation:

```js
export default {
  fillKivaferkoi (state, data) {
    state.kivaferkoi = data
  },

  editPicked (state, data) {
    state.kivaferkoi.picked = data
  }
}
```

actions:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  fetch (context, token) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get(process.env.api_url + '/kivaferkoi', {
        headers: {
          authorization: token
        }
      })
        .then((response) => {
          context.commit('fillKivaferkoi', response.data)
          resolve(response)
        }).catch((e) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.error(e)
          reject(e)
        })
    })
  },

  update (context, data) {
    const token = data.token
    delete data.token

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.put(process.env.api_url + '/kivaferkoi/', data.value, {
        headers: {
          authorization: token
        }
      })
        .then((response) => {
          context.commit('editPicked', response.data)
          resolve(response)
        }).catch((e) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.error(e)
          reject(e)
        })
    })
  }
}
```

and my vue component :

```js
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row class="d-flex justify-center ">
      <v-col cols="3">
        <v-card
          color="secondary"
          rounded="lg"
          flat
        >
          <v-card-title>
            Picked one
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-list color="secondary">
              <template v-for="(item, i) in picked">
                <v-list-item :key="i">
                  <v-list-item-avatar>
                    <v-img class="avatar" :src="item.avatar ? item.avatar : avatar" />
                  </v-list-item-avatar>
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                      {{ item.name }}
                    </v-list-item-title>
                    <v-list-item-subtitle>
                      {{ item.surname }}
                    </v-list-item-subtitle>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-autocomplete
                  :key="'combobox' + i"
                  v-model="item.pickedSummary"
                  :items="prositSummary"
                  flat
                  solo
                  background-color="background"
                />
              </template>
            </v-list>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Kivaferoi',
  computed: {
    picked: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.kivaferkoi.kivaferkoi.picked
      },

      set (value) {
        this.$store.dispatch('kivaferkoi/update', { token: this.$auth.getToken('local', value) })
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace data in assignment with copy (spread, for exaple, like below). Objects (and arrays too) assigned as links in JS, so when you change picked array anywhere, you mutate it in the store too.

```
fillKivaferkoi (state, data) {
    state.kivaferkoi = {...data}
  },

  editPicked (state, data) {
    state.kivaferkoi.picked = [...data]
  }
```

Comment: I doesn't reach the Set() part so i can not test your solution mate

Comment: "item" is a part of "picked" array, which linked with picked array in store. Model of v-autocomplete is item.pickedSummary (i'm don't see any "pickedSummary" in store, may be you trying to create it there? it also store mutation)/ Any change you doing in component is projected to store. To avoid it just try to assign objects in store as copies, not as links as shown higher

Comment: It does not work unfortunatly, i start to think thath i might change the way i'm doing it because i can't find any good way to do it.